# why is Flink ListCheckPointed deprecated for operator state

Tags: apache-flink

As this [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/checkpoint/CheckpointedFunction.html) says: Checkpointing some state that is part of the function object itself is possible in a simpler way by directly implementing the ListCheckpointed interface.

implementing the full-fledged CheckpointedFunction interface, IMHO, is tedious. With ListCheckpointed, I would only have to maintain member variables, which is more intuitive. Otherwise I would have to maintain a ListState member

Answer (score 0):

`ListCheckpointed` was deprecated because it allowed for the use of some serialization shortcuts that don't play nice with state migration.